# Separate localstorages

Tags: html, local-storage

I have 1 site under foo.com/test1/test1.html and another at foo.com/test2/test2.html

test1.html looks like this:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script>
        document.ready = function(){
            var name = localStorage.getItem("name");
            if(name){
                console.log("name is defined");
            }else{
                console.log("name is not defined");
                localStorage.setItem("name", "test1");
            }
            $('#name').text(name);
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <p id="name"></p>
</body>
</html>
```

And test2.html is like this:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script>
        document.ready = function(){
            var name = localStorage.getItem("name");
            if(name){
                console.log("name is defined");
            }else{
                console.log("name is not defined");
                localStorage.setItem("name", "test2");
            }
            $('#name').text(name);
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <p id="name"></p>
</body>
</html>
```

My question is that is it possible to achieve that that if I go to test1, the value of name is "test1" and if I go to test2 the name will be test2. Basically I suspect that I need to name them differently but I rather not do that. Is there any good work around for this?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: PHP or any server side scripting is not allowed at this stage. Would you express this in more details?

Comment: LocalStorage is set per domain, so no, you can't do that. Why not simply use different names? Or - if you want the code to be as similar as possible, use a JavaScript variable to store a prefix, ie: ugh, freaking hate "Enter to save" - imagine you have: var prefix="test1". Then when you get/set the item, do: localStorage.getItem(prefix + "name")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

local storage is defined per domain. You should keep objects in localstorage to maintain page context.

Here is solution to do it.

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script>
        document.ready = function(){
            var thispage = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("page1"));
            if(thispage.name){
                console.log("name is defined");
            }else{
                console.log("name is not defined");
                var obj={name : "test1"}

                localStorage.setItem("page1", JSON.stringify(obj));
            }

        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <p id="name"></p>
</body>
</html>
```

similar to all pages.

Comment: Thanks. My solution is similar to this.